# ASP.NET IsPostback always returing false

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm facing strange issue in ASP.NET based webforms application. `IsPostback` from code always getting false even application is post backed while accessing application from outside the deployment server. But, its working fine when i using application in deployment server. Two different behaviors when accessing from server and outside the server. What will be them problem? I'm not getting any clue or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details. If the button on the same page uses post-back url, or a hyper link (to the same page), then IsPostBack will always be false.

If some button or event on the page causes a post-back, then IsPostBack will be true.

so, the status of IsPostBack will depend on the how/what/why/where you are triggering code on that page.

but, as a FYI:

Hyperlinks or buttons with a post-back URL start the page over again, and this includes IsPostBack being false.

Same will occur if this page is a child page of a master page, and you use the menu navigation in the master page to navigate to the current page, or if you use menu bar navigate again to the same page.

Without the example markup or just the "small" amount of code your using here, we really are guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here providing more details. I'm using asp.net button control in my page, on click of this post back operation triggering. Now, deployed this in my IIS server. When accessing application through url in the server, IsPostBack operation retuning true once click on button, this is as expected. When accessing same url outside the deployment server and clicked on the same button, ISPostback is returning false.

Comment: same url and button operations working differently , when accessing within deployment server and outside the deployment server.

Comment: Hum, I wonder if some js library or link is messed up on the server deployment. You could just before hitting the button, hit f12 to bring up browser debug tools, and then click on that button - maybe their is a javascript error. But, to be fair, it not quite clear why IsPostBack would change behavior's after deployment. It also possible I suppose that the page in question has viewstate disabled, but again, that should work the same on both development vs deployed. Try the f12 suggesting, see if errors exist in the deployed page. Also, try deploying with debug=true for production.